# adding row to short table row won't insert at correct spot

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table that is populated dynamically from a database.

I want to click the button and insert a new row after the row marked with "z", but instead, it is inserted after the row marked with "y".

How do I insert the new row after "z" ?

```js
$(".addRow").click(function() {

  var row = $(this).closest(".baseRow");
  var rowspan = parseInt($(row).attr("rowspan"));
  rowspan++;

  $(".baseRow").attr("rowspan", rowspan);
  $(".addCR").attr("rowspan", rowspan);

  var r = "<tr class='shortRow'>";
  r += "<td></td>";
  r += "<td></td>";
  r += "<td></td>";
  r += "</tr>";

  //$(row).next(".lastRow").before(r);
  $(row).after(r);

});
```

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}

td {
  height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <tr class='baseRow' rowspan='2'>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>
      <button class='addRow'>+</button>
    </td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='shortRow'>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='lastRow'>
    <td colspan='8'>lastrow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to add the row with 3 columns directly under 'z', or under 'x' as well?

Comment: I probably should of been more clear that there could be many "lastrows". Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/mn76upjL/29/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mn76upjL/42/).

1. You shouldn't have `rowspan` on `<tr>` elements.
2. Your [`$(el).next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function only checks the next element, and empty if it doesn't meet the requirements. So I replaced with a [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to get all until the next ".lastrow" class.

```js
$(".addRow").click(function() {

  var row = $(this).closest(".baseRow");
  var rowspan = parseInt($(row).children('td:eq(0)').attr("rowspan")) + 1;

  $(".addCR", row).attr("rowspan", rowspan);

  var r = "<tr class='shortRow'>";
  r += "<td></td>";
  r += "<td></td>";
  r += "<td></td>";
  r += "</tr>";
  row.nextUntil('.lastRow').eq(0).after(r);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}

td {
  height: 17px;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  background:
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <tr class='baseRow'>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>
      <button class='addRow'>+</button>
    </td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='shortRow'>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>z</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='lastRow'>
    <td colspan='8'>lastrow</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='baseRow'>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>
      <button class='addRow'>+</button>
    </td>
    <td class='addCR' rowspan='2'>x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='shortRow'>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>z</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='lastRow'>
    <td colspan='8'>lastrow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping each group of baseRow,shortRow and lastRow in it's own `<tbody>`

Then you could do

```
row.closest('tbody').find('.lastRow').before(r);
//OR
row.siblings('.lastRow').before(r);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mn76upjL/38/)**</kbd>

Comment: I probably should of been more clear that there could be many "lastrows". Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/mn76upjL/29/

Comment: The simplest thing would be wrap each grouping in a `<tbody>`. A table can have any number of `<tbody>` and that would create a simple container to look within

Comment: Updated demo and answer to reflect `<tbody>` approach

Comment: @charlietfl, your most recent update throws the rowspan count off, cause the 'lastRow' becomes "nested".

Comment: @SunnyPatel well I'm sure OP can sort that out

Answer (score 0):

the answer was to use

```
  $(row).nextAll(".lastRow").eq(0).before(r);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/mn76upjL/46/)

Comment: I think all of us have viable options. Though you still shouldn't have the `rowspan` attribute on your `<tr>` elements.

Comment: yes, you are correct about rowspan on tr. I've removed it from my code. Thanks